# Sorting a dataset based on 2 columns & computing averages of sub-datasets based on the 2 columns' contents

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set that details polling data in different states and the percentage of people who have voted for either DEM or REP in that state.
[What my data frame looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLi51.png)

I'm essentially trying to find the average percentage of people in X state voting for either DEM or REP. So my output would be something like:

New Hampshire | DEM | 55%
New Hampshire | REP | 45%
Maine | DEM | 45%
Maine | REP | 54%
etc.

I initially thought of simply iterating over the entire dataset, and assigning new pct variables for each state's DEM percentage or REP percentage, but I felt that that is inefficient.

I'm thinking of sorting the data such that it has state1, DEM | state1, REP | state2, DEM | state3, REP etc. and then finding averages. But I am not too experienced with pandas (which is what I'm attempting to use). Perhaps someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, use [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`GroupBy.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) :

```
cols = ["state", "party"]

(
    pd.concat([df_house, df_senate],
              ignore_index=True)
        .groupby(cols, as_index=False)
        .mean(numeric_only=True)
        .sort_values(by=cols)
)
```

This will return a (`pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`) that you can assign to a variable:

```
df_average = pd.concat([df_house, df_senate], ignore_index=True).groupby(cols, as_index=False).mean(numeric_only=True).sort_values(by=cols)
```

Answer (score 0):

try using
`df.groupby(['state','party'])['pct'].mean()`